# MultiSearch API for N number of queries

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following example code and number of queries that I send depends on how much SearchRequestBuilder do I construct, and add them to MultiSearchResponse.

```
public static void requestBuilder(ArrayList<String> formulae) {

        Client client = TransportClient.builder().build()
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",9300)));

        SearchRequestBuilder srb1 = client
                .prepareSearch(index)
                .setSource(formulae.get(1));
        SearchRequestBuilder srb2 = client
                .prepareSearch(index)
                .setSource(formulae.get(2));

        MultiSearchResponse sr = client.prepareMultiSearch()
                .add(srb1)
                .add(srb2)
                .execute()
                .actionGet();

        long nbHits = 0;
        for (MultiSearchResponse.Item item : sr.getResponses()){
            SearchResponse response = item.getResponse();
            nbHits += response.getHits().getTotalHits();
            System.out.println(response);
        }
        System.out.println(nbHits); 
        System.out.println(formulae.size());


    client.close(); 


    }
```

IS there any way that I can generate [size of formulae] amount of SearchRequestBuilder? So I can query each element of my ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate over your formulae and add them to your multi search one by one and then fire the multi search request.

```
MultiSearchRequestBuilder sr = client.prepareMultiSearch();
for (String formula : formulae) {
    SearchRequestBuilder srb = client
            .prepareSearch(index)
            .setSource(formula);
    sr.add(srb);
}
MultiSearchResponse resp = sr.execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I get errors, for the 1st line, i.e.:Type mismatch: cannot convert from MultiSearchRequestBuilder to MultiSearchResponse

Comment: I still get errors for the first and last line: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from MultiSearchRequestBuilder to 
 MultiSearchRequest   
The method execute() is undefined for the type MultiSearchRequest

Comment: it seems to work now. Thank you ! 
 I get some results, but for some reason I get NullPointerExpectation as well, maybe there is a limit for the number of queries, not sure :)

Comment: Where do you get that NullPointerException?

Comment: it's not the problem of your code. I get this error when I calculate the number of hits.

Comment: Well, let me know if I can help.

Comment: thank you for your help, I tried but did not work. I'm trying to get number of hits, and values of some fields, but I fail. For example, hier I get  NullPointerExceptation:  nbHits += response.getHits().getTotalHits();